# ListView positions issue on NotifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I am using custom list `adapter` with `CheckBox` for my `ListActivity`. When I provide list to adapter for the first time, it shows positions of item bottom to top. Means position 0 being the bottom most list item and N being the top item. When I select top most element, it gives me position N, I remove item from list by N index and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`. The issue is it removes the item at index 0. And the second issue is after notifyDataSetChanged, now the top most element is showing position 0 and bottom most item showing N position. What is the issue and how to resolve? I am newbie to Android so please help accordingly.

I am posting removal of items code:

### Code

```
private OnClickListener deleteItemsListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = emails.getCheckedPositions();
            for(int p : positions)
            {
                messges.remove(p);
            }

            emails.notifyDataSetChanged();
            emails.clearList();
            emailListView.invalidate();

            deleteItems.setText("");
            deleteItems.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

        }
    };
```

Where messges is the `ArrayList<Object>`. Following code initializes the list and adapter.

```
mmessges = new ArrayList<Object>();
emails = new GMailAdapter(this, messges);
emailListView.setAdapter(emails);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = emails.getCheckedPosiotions();
int[] positionArray = new int[position.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < positionArray; i++) {
    positionArray[i]= mmessges.size() - positions.get(i);
}

for (int p = 0; p < posiotionArray.length(); p++) {
    messges.remove(p);
}

emails.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think its the hack which only works for one time before notifyDataSetChanged. Actually when there are four items then positions are 0,1,2,3 with 0 being the bottom most element and 3 being the top most element. When i delete first two elements then top most element should have position 1 but it is giving me position 2. it is causing crash. Is there any need to put whole adapter code here? or you have understood my problem?